# Strange behavior with parskip; changing a letter takes a lot of space

Tags: spacing, parskip

This question is merely out of curiosity. After correcting a typo ("ad" cnanged into "at"), I noticed that changing a single letter changes completely the output (in the first case the compiler cannot make it in two lines, while in the second case it takes much less than two full lines.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    Hint: for a fixed $y$, let $f(x):=\sin(x+y)-\sin(x)\cos(y)-\cos(x)\sin(y)$; prove that $f''=-f$ (so that $f$ equals its Taylor series centered ad $0$) and $f(0)=f'(0)=0$.

    Hint: for a fixed $y$, let $f(x):=\sin(x+y)-\sin(x)\cos(y)-\cos(x)\sin(y)$; prove that $f''=-f$ (so that $f$ equals its Taylor series centered at $0$) and $f(0)=f'(0)=0$.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Can anyone explain why this happens?**

Comment: An impressive demonstration!

Comment: the parfill option forces 30pt free space at the end of the paragraph, and now you are just under this limit.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I would upvote that answer!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes A demonstration that `parskip` should not be used, you mean… `;-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parfill option forces 30pt free space at the end of the paragraph, and now you are just under this limit. By slightly reducing the value you can avoid the line break in the first version too (I removed `inputenc`, as it is no longer required in a current LaTeX):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[parfill=29.1pt]{parskip}
\usepackage[top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    Hint: for a fixed $y$, let $f(x):=\sin(x+y)-\sin(x)\cos(y)-\cos(x)\sin(y)$; prove that $f''=-f$ (so that $f$ equals its Taylor series centered ad $0$) and $f(0)=f'(0)=0$.

    Hint: for a fixed $y$, let $f(x):=\sin(x+y)-\sin(x)\cos(y)-\cos(x)\sin(y)$; prove that $f''=-f$ (so that $f$ equals its Taylor series centered at $0$) and $f(0)=f'(0)=0$.
\end{document}
```

[image]